# JQuery select button element by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML:

> ```
> <button class="btn btn-primary cl-width" ng-click="search()">
>   <i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Search</button>
> <button class="btn cl-width" ng-click="criteriaModel.reset()">
>   <i class="icon> iconfa-undo"></i>&nbsp;Reset</button>
> ```

My jQuery:

```
$("button[ng-click:'search()]")
```

It shows an error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: button
>   [ng-click:'search()]

Doesn't jQuery support attribute selector for button element?
I can achieve that by `$("button.btn-primary")`, but I don't think that is good enough.

How could I select a button element by its attribute?

Comment: Ya you have a syntax error in your selector... What about just reading the selector you are using?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try

```
$("button[ng-click='search()']")
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
$("button[ng-click='search()']").text()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nppU4/)

Answer (score 1):

please use the following

```
$("button[ng-click='search()']")
```

Comment: No, the extra space after `button` space makes it not working.